# geotools filter CQLException: Encountered “t”

Tags: geotools, cql-filter, cql

I am querying a simple feature type schema:
`r:Long:index=join,*g:Point:srid=4326,di:Integer:index=join,al:Float,s:Float,b:Float,an:Float,he:Float,ve:Float,t:Float,m:Boolean,i:Boolean,ts:Long;geomesa.table.sharing='true',geomesa.indices='attr:4:3,records:2:3,z2:3:3',geomesa.table.sharing.prefix='\\u0001'`

with the query expression: `r = 31 AND di = 5 AND BBOX(g, -38.857822, -76.111145, -74.64091, -38.61907) AND al <= 39.407307 AND s <= 1.6442835 AND b <= 83.14717 AND an <= 87.0774 AND he <= 40.89476 AND ve <= 88.761566 AND t <= 44.786507 AND m = true AND i = true.`

but it throws an exception saying `Encountered "t" at line 1, column 195.`

Here is my exception log detail:

```
org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLException: Encountered "t" at line 1, column 195.
Was expecting one of:
    <NOT> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "include" ...
    "exclude" ...
    "(" ...
    "[" ...
     Parsing : r = 31 AND di = 5 AND BBOX(g, -38.857822, -76.111145, -74.64091, -38.61907) AND al <= 39.407307 AND s <= 1.6442835 AND b <= 83.14717 AND an <= 87.0774 AND he <= 40.89476 AND ve <= 88.761566 AND t <= 44.786507 AND m = true AND i = true.
    at org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQLCompiler.compileFilter(CQLCompiler.java:106)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.commons.CompilerUtil.parseFilter(CompilerUtil.java:196)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQL.toFilter(CQL.java:134)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.cql2.CQL.toFilter(CQL.java:113)
    at com.hps.GeomesaClient.query(GeomesaClient.java:134)
    at com.hps.Reader.run(Reader.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to determine, why it's throwing an exception on querying with the attribute named `t`. Whereas if I remove attribute `t` from the query, it works as expected.

Is `t` a reserved key or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The letter `t` is considered to be UTC token(ignoring the case). Referring the code: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/cql/src/main/jjtree/ECQLGrammar.jjt#L180-L187

or we can double quotes to force use an attribute.

geotools developer filed a bug report so this doesn't get lost. Here is the [link](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5722).